# Error in android studio after project build

Tags: android, android-studio

I have started a new project in android studio but after gradle build it shows error like:

```
Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
```

In project's dimens.xml file it contains some anonymous code like below:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
<library name="Gradle: com.githu
```

I have not write anything it comes on its own after project's very first build.
I am failed to understand what does it mean and where it comes from though i have started new project.

Someone please let me know how to resolve this issue.

**THANKS**

Comment: You have some miscellaneous code in `dimens.xml`. Remove it and then run .

Comment: are you sure you are not missing any xml opening & closing tags `<`,`\>`

Comment: This problem occured just after very first project build.